# Inserting HTML formatted text in a .docx template

Tags: php, html, xml, docx, phpword

I have some .docx templates on which I need to insert text generated by a php script and formatted with HTML markups.

I have tried using phpword template manipulation option, but you can't enter full blocks, you can only enter a non-formatted single-line value.

There is the solution to convert the template in HTML, insert the generated text, then save it back with a msword MIME, but then it would not fully keep the integrity of headers and footers.

Next one I found is phpdocx, but 249 euros just to use the embedHTML function is too much for me.

So my next idea would be the following:

1) insert a tag in the word template : {{{tag}}}

2) load the template .docx file in my php script as an XML stream.

3) create a .docx document with phpword containing my generated text between 2 
tags {{{tag1}}} and {{{tag2}}}

4) load the document generated in 3) as an XML stream and extract the blocks between the 2 tags.

5) Insert the block extracted in 4) to replace the initial {{{tag}}} in the XML stream loaded in 2)

But I'm really not sure it would work as I don't really understand how Word build its XML...

Is XML structure hierarchival so this idea of a block replacement by another one including subblocks could work ?

Comment: What is your concrete programming question here? Asking for advice tends to be subjective and then it's easily to fall into off-topic. So you should better try if what you thought-out did work or not and if you run into a concrete problem, ask it as a programming question.

Comment: Just edited, the thing is that I'm not very experienced and programing this would take me a day of work, so if someone with the knowledge could at least tell me if it worth trying it would be fantastic. Or also someone could come with a better idea how to do that....

Comment: yes it could work, but it must not work. XML most often *is* hierarchical but it depends on the format *that* XML you have represents. You should give it a try and report back if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the pandoc library in linux which is meant for this very purpose.